# how do i make gpio high in sama5d36.dtsi file for getting android display

Tags: android, io, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

I'm new to android and embedded field.We are using SAMA5D3 board and to get android run on the display we have short pins.Instead of that,I think we can make GPIO HIGH LOW in AT91 -SAMA5D3.dtsi file for turning on android display.Please somebody help how to make this pin high or should I add any patch ??

Comment: Do not edit the  **sama5d36.dtsi** or **sama5d3.dtsi** file, which are for the standard and generic SoC. Since you are making a board-level change (rather than customizing the SoC), make the changes to the top-level board file, e.g. your **.dts** file. *"we have short pins"* -- Instead of trying to use jargon (and end up not making any sense), explain exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

Comment: I want to make GPIO HIGH to get Led back light for Android display. I don't know in which .DTS file I have to set this pin. I want to make pin PC0 to high. Can anybody help on this .

Comment: You can add it in at91-sama5d3_xplained.dts